# Asp.net WebApi supports json, xml, jsonp?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, formatter, content-negotiation

This question is specific to **Asp.Net WebApi**.

In my global file, I've put:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
```

JsonpMediaTypeFormatter is custom Jsonp formatter that I have.

After this, when i call,

```
function jsonpCallback(data) {
        alert('in' + data);
        var list = $('#courses');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var course = data[i];
            list.append('<li>' + course.name + '</li>');
        }
    }
$.getJSON("http://localhost:64009/api/courses?callback=?", null, jsonpCallback);
```

It worked.

But, from my global file, if I remove

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
```

Then it doesn't work.

What if i want to support multiple formatters?
As I can use HttpClient for CORS and ask for xml or json or jsop?

Can someone please advice?

Comment: You should get your question and post it here. If the other site is down, then people won't be able to see it.

Comment: As per request:
I've added jsonp formatter to my GlobalConfiguration
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
Then i try to call my webapi using format that's not supported (dataType: "x-vcard")..that means it should return json:

Comment: $.ajax({
       url: "/api/courses",
       dataType: "x-vcard",
       type: "GET",
       success: function (data) {
           var list = $('#courses');
           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               var course = data[i];
               list.append('<li>' + course.name + '</li>');
           }
       },
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('error');
           alert(jqXHR.statusText + " ----- " + jqXHR.responseText);
       }
   });

Comment: Response from fiddler:

49
[{"id":0,"name":".net"},{"id":1,"name":"oData"},{"id":2,"name":"WebApi"}]
0

And it returns json, but my ajax callback goes to error and shows the following message:
parseerror - [{"id":0,"name":".net"},{"id":1,"name":"oData"},{"id":2,"name":"WebApi"}]
why it's not calling success callback function?

Comment: in your JsonpMediaTypeFormatter, what do you have for you SupportedMediaTypes ?

Comment: also insert your jsonpmediaformatter at the top of the list, ie configuration.formatters.insert(0, new jsonpmediatypeformatter())